# &self -- Do I get the address for the object

Tags: objective-c

I create 2 objects of the same class.
When in a method I do this:

```
NSLog(@"This object is on address %p\n",&self);`
```

I get the same address for two distinct objects of the same class.

When I do this outside the class:

```
NSLog(@"This object is on address %p\n",&myObject);
and
NSLog(@"This object is on address %p\n",&anotherObject);
```

I do get two distinct addresses.
Am I missing something about how self works? Shouldn't it be a pointer to the object?

Different angle:
How do I get an object's address from within a method of that object's class?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is a irrelevant result, as its the address of self in the current stack frame, not the address of self in the calling function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Objective C a reference to a class is already a pointer.  By taking the address of `self` or `myObject` you are getting the address where the variable is stored (likely on the stack).

So just printing:

```
NSLog(@"This object is on address %p\n", self);
```

or

```
 NSLog(@"This object is on address %p\n", myObject);
```

Will print the address of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `%p` does not require you to pass the address of the variable.  It is a void* operation.  I am not at my development machine to test this myself, but try doing:

```
NSLog(@"This object is on address %p\n", self);
```

Comment: No, you MUST pass the address, due to how varargs work in C. It's not magic.